# DropDownList Multiple Selection, code only sees 1 item selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am working on a webpage with a new type of form selection that I have not worked with.

In short, I want to be able to select multiple users from a `DropDownList` and add them to a new record in my database.

I have a working asp.net form function (a Bootstrap jQuery script), and can select multiple items properly. However, when I hit my submit button to create the object, my code only sees 1 item is selected, rather than multiple.

I understand that this code is not native to C# and ASP.NET, but I was wondering how I should go about retrieving the selected state from ALL item properly.

C# and ASPX Code:

```
Project project = Project.GetByIdentification(ID);
foreach (ListItem item in ddlAssigned.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        ProjectUser newUser = project.ProjectUsers.AddNew();
        newUser.ProjectID = ID;
        newUser.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(item.Value);
        project.Save();
    }
}

<label class="control-label" for="ddlAssigned">Assigned Users:</label>
<div class="controls">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAssigned" runat="server" multiple="multiple"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Common/Scripts/bootstrap.multiselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document.getElementById('ddlAssigned')).multiselect({ includeSelectAllOption: true });
    });
</script>
```

To outline the above code: "ProjectUser" is a CHILD object of "Project", and only has two fields: ProjectID and UserID, both are primary keys, so each entry will be unique.

The ASPX code has a javascript element, that utilizes this functionality: https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect

It is just styling. I tried both with and without the script, and the same problem is arising.

The problem I am having is in line 4, "if (item.Selected)". In my DropDownList, I have 2+ users selected, however this IF statement only runs true ONCE. It only sees the FIRST selected item as selected, and the rest are not selected, according to the code.

How can I make my code recognize multiple selections? Any plugins or scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the control you need to use is a listbox instead of a drop down list?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.selectionmode.aspx

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_listbox.asp

Comment: Yeahhhhh. I feel dumb. The person who told me the design specs of the page used the words "Drop Down List" and I kept that in my head as I wrote the page. Forgot the ListBox even existed!